# What to do when IMAP UIDVALIDITY decreases

Tags: imap

[RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) states that

> If unique identifiers from an earlier session fail to persist in this
> session, the unique identifier validity value MUST be greater than the
> one used in the earlier session.

I know that "MUST" is not really negotiable, but what should a client do when it receives a `UIDVALIDITY` that is smaller than the one it got when it connected the last time? Should it assume that UIDs have persisted, or should it discard downloaded messages anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot assume that UIDs have persisted from the last UIDVALIDITY value it saw.

Suppose it sees validity 100 and UID 1000, and caches that. Later it sees validity 101 and UID 1, then it cannot use cached information about the old 1000 any more, but it can cache UID 1. If it then sees validity 100 again, then it is permitted to use the old cached information about 1000, but not the one about 1.

Rather far-fetched. In practice I don't expect anyone to bother doing this. No servers make it worthwhile. But you asked ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the UIDVALIDITY changes in any way, any cached information about the folder should be purged.